# Initializing nested object properties

Tags: c#

I have a class called employee which has a field called insurance which is of type insurance like this

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public Insurance Insurance;
}
```

I have another class called Insurance

```
public class Insurance
{
    public int PolicyId;
    public String PolicyName;
}
```

Now in the main program i want to do something like

```
var myEmployee = new Employee();
myEmployee.Name = "Jhon";
myEmployee.Insurance.PolicyId = 123 ;
myEmployee.Insurance.PolicyName = "Life Time" ;
```

C# is complaining and i know how to fix it by creating a instance of the Insurance class.

My question is can i somehow assign the values for the fields in the way i want to do it in the main program using like

**

```
myEmployee.Insurance.PolicyId = 123 ;
myEmployee.Insurance.PolicyName = "Life Time" ;
```

**
I tried

```
 public class Employee
    {

        public Employee()
        {
            Insurance Insurance = new Insurance();
        }

        public String Name;
        public Insurance Insurance;



        public class Insurance
        {
            public int PolicyId;
            public String PolicyName;
        } 
    }
```

In the main method when i try

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var joe = new Employee();
            joe.Name = "Joe";
            joe.Insurance.

        }
```

I get this error-

**Error 2   Ambiguity between 'ConsoleApplication1.Employee.Insurance' and 'ConsoleApplication1.Employee.Insurance' c:\users\lenovo\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    15  17  ConsoleApplication1**

Comment: I want to use myEmployee.Insurance.PolicyId using 2 dots.Is this even possible in any object oriented langauge .

Comment: You defined a class "Insurance" and a property "Insurance" both within Employee. Must be uniquely named within the class, otherwise it won't know which to work on. Make Insurance it's own class, or rename one of them. I updated my answer to reflect your edits and resolve this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could instantiate Insurance in Employee's constructor so it is done automatically for you.  You could provide it default values to ensure it is understood that is not yet defined to be valid when accessed later on.

```
public class Employee
{
    Insurance Insurance { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        this.Insurance = new Insurance() { PolicyId = -1 };
    }
}

public class Insurance
{
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
}
```

Or to keep the classes nested:

```
public class Employee
{
    Insurance InsurancePolicy { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        this.InsurancePolicy = new Insurance() { PolicyId = -1 };
    }
    public class Insurance
    {
        public int PolicyId { get; set; }
        public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Without requiring changes to your `Employee` class, you could use object initializers:

```
var myEmployee = new Employee 
{
    Name = "Jhon",
    Insurance = new Insurance
    {
        PolicyId = 123,
        PolicyName = "Life Time"
    }
};
```

Alternatively, and maybe preferably, you can have the `Employee` class create a new instance of `Insurance` either in its constructor (as in the other answers), or one other option would be to do it in the `Insurance` property getter itself, so it's instantiated only if you use it. Here's an example of the latter:

```
class Employee 
{
    private Insurance insurance;

    public Insurance Insurance
    {
        get
        {
            if (insurance == null)
            {
                insurance = new Insurance();
            }
            return insurance;
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, I would suggest that you don't build classes that have all public fields unless you really know that's what you want. Instead, I would consider using *properties* over fields. I have incorporated other's suggestions into the following code, and provided my own:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee() 
    {
        this.Insurance = new Insurance();
    }

    // Perhaps another constructor for the name?
    public Employee(string name)
        : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Insurance Insurance { get; private set; }
}

public class Insurance
{
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That *singleton-like* approach doesn't sound very useful in this case. Instantiating in the constructor is more than enough, and it also avoids a null-check every time Insurance is trying to be accessed.

Comment: It would be better if the Insurance class was a heavy object, though. I'll give you that.

Comment: @KappaG3: I agree 100%, just wanted to show another possible approach.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, but how are you going to assign something that is belonging to a `null` object?
You need to instantiate `Insurance` in `Employee`'s constructor.

```
public Employee()
{
     this.Insurance = new Insurance();
}
```

EDIT Regarding your comment:
Following this approach you **will** be able to access `myEmplyee.Insurance.PolicyID` with *two dots*. The constructor is *inside* Employee's class, so you won't have to type anything more than what you already tried to do, once you implement it.

Comment: I generally do this and prefer it over any other ways.  It works great for instantiating collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a constructor for your employee that will instantiate `Insurance`

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Insurance = new Insurance();
    }
    public string Name;
    public Insurance Insurance;
}
```

Comment: `this` keyword is redundant unless used for extension methods.

Comment: It avoids confusion when the member's name is the same as its type.

Comment: @HighCore  the `this` keyword is more expressive, and it is useful when you're trying to read more complex code.  especially when you're reading code that you yourself didn't write

Comment: @jhon.smith the error you're getting is because there are 2 meanings to `Employee.Insurance`  You might want to move your `Insurance` class to outside of `Employee`